# why the chat-widget read property 'style' is showing null

Tags: javascript, html

I want to hide the `Widget-chat` but it showing the error that property of style is null. please help me thanks in advance

```
 document.getElementById("chat-widget").style.display='none';

  <Widget 
   id ="chat-widget"
   title="My new awesome title" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call the function `getElementById()` after the element is created, otherwise it won't find anything and will return null.

If it's inside an external js file, put the `<script src="..."></script>` just before the end of the html body.